# how to fix that using writeNullable[List[T]] throws a nullpointer exception in play2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I use play2(2.2.3 with scala 2.10.4) and I define a data structure like this：

```
    package model

    case class FileData(id: Int, name: String, size: String, date: String, children: Option[List[FileData]])

    object FileData {
        def sample : List[FileData] = {
            val file1 = FileData(31,"eclipse.exe","56 KB","05/19/2009",None)
            val file2 = FileData(32,"eclipse.ini","1 KB","04/20/2010",None)
            val fold1 = FileData(3,"eclipse","","01/20/2010",Some(List(file1,file2)))
            List(fold1)
        }
    }
```

Then I try to serialize it to json.

```
    object TreeGridData extends Controller {
        def getData = Action {
            implicit request =>
    //            implicit val dataWrites: FileDataWrites.type = FileDataWrites
                Ok(Json.toJson(FileData.sample)).as("application/json")
        }
        ...
```

Firstly writing a object that extends Writes[FileData]:

```
    object FileDataWrites extends Writes[FileData] {
        def writes(o: FileData): JsValue = {
            Json.obj (
                "id" -> o.id,
                "name" -> o.name,
                "size" -> o.size,
                "date" -> o.date,
                "children" -> o.children.fold[JsValue](JsNull)(l => JsArray(l.map(FileDataWrites.writes(_))))
            )
        }
    }
```

It's easy to write and it works out fine.

Then,I try using another way using JsPath:

```
        implicit val fileDataWrites : Writes[FileData] = (
            (JsPath \ "id").write[Int] and
            (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
            (JsPath \ "size").write[String] and
            (JsPath \ "date").write[String] and
            // recursion (the fileDataWrites is implicit)
            (JsPath \ "children").writeNullable[List[FileData]]
        )(unlift(FileData.unapply _ ))
```

There is no compilation error.But when run the code a nullpointer exception is thrown：

```
    play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]
            at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
            at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
            at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:166) [play_2
    .10.jar:2.2.3]
            at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:163) [play_2
    .10.jar:2.2.3]
            at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library.jar:na]
            at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185) [scala-library.jar:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
            at play.api.libs.json.Json$.toJson(Json.scala:83) ~[play-json_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
            at play.api.libs.json.DefaultWrites$$anon$3$$anonfun$writes$2.apply(Writes.scala:166) ~[play-json_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
            at play.api.libs.json.DefaultWrites$$anon$3$$anonfun$writes$2.apply(Writes.scala:166) ~[play-json_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
            at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

I have no idea about how to fix it.Could you help me?

Comment: Try `(JsPath \ "children").lazyWrite[List[FileData]](fileDataWrites)`

Comment: @LimbSoup the code can not compile because the fileDataWrites is the type of Writes[FileData] but not Writes[List[FileData]]. _type mismatch; found : play.api.libs.json.Writes[model.FileData] required: play.api.libs.json.Writes[List[model.FileData]]_

Comment: `Writes.list(fileDataWrites)`